# Android getBearing uses the phone compass or GPS coordinates?

Tags: android, gps, location, android-location

Can anyone tell me if “getBearing” uses the phone compass (magnetic north) or simply calculates the bearing storing one coordinate where the user has passed and calculate the bearing using the actual coordinate (true north)?

I see from the reference that “bearingTo” uses the coordinates to calculate the phone actual bearing (using true north), but with the “getBearing” I can’t understand how it works and if it uses the compass/magnetic field sensor (magnetic north) or simply de GPS coordinates(true north).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Thanks

Comment: The documentation says: "Bearing is the horizontal direction of travel of this device, and is not related to the device orientation". If is not related to the device orientation that means that has to use stored waypoints to calculate the bearing.

Answer (score 1):

bearingTo gives the initial bearing in a great circle course towards user point. This not the direct bearing to user point but shortest over earth. Google great circle and rhumb lines. For most apps it does not matter as its being updated regularly but if compared to magnetic or doing calculations it throws everything.( It did me I use rhumb bearings)

getBearing gives a "direction of horizontal travel" from the last two location (gps) points.